# Clone from one table to antoher

Tags: javascript, html-table, clone

I just saw in another post the solution, though when I try using it in my code it doesn't work.

I'm trying to add the item on one table to the other one through the button. Any help is appreciated.

html

```
<div id="container">

    <input type="text" name="search" id="search"  placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del examen..." size="50">
    </input>

    <table id="proctable" >
        <tr>
            <th>Examen</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>hola</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td><input class="addBtn" type="button" value="Agregar"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <hr>

    <div>
       <table id="comptable">
          <tr class="header">
              <th>Examen</th>
              <th>Precio</th>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var items = [];

        $(".addBtn").on("click", function() {
            var newTr = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
            items.push(newTr);
            newTr.appendTo( $("#comptable") );

        });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/45nfvg9j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript actually works as intended.  The jsFiddle was broken because of two little things:

1. You had script open and close tags around your javascript.  jsFiddle was actually showing a yellow note "Input plain JavaScript code, no HTML."
2. Input tags need to be self-closing, like this: `<input class="addBtn" type="button" value="Agregar"/>`, not `<input class="addBtn" type="button" value="Agregar"></input>`

Comment: Hello, thank you for that. I took the open and close tags from the javascript, the code is still not working.

Comment: If you fix problem #2 as well, your code works.  Look at the html in your jsFiddle - the invalid input tag is highlighted in red!

Comment: Fixed them both, still having the same problem

Comment: Oh, your jsFiddle also doesn't have jQuery, so "$" throws an exception.  To fix, click on the cog at the top right of the javascript panel and change "no library" to "jQuery 3.1" or whatever version of jQuery you use.